# Snooze button not working for iCal on Lion and Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, ical

I've been using iCal (now called Calendar.app) to view my Google Calendar calendars for a long time and generally haven't had a problem.  However, in the last few weeks or months I've noticed that when I hit the "Snooze" button on iCal alerts, they never come back again like you would expect.

This definitely didn't used to be a problem but I don't know what changed.  I've noticed the problem on both Lion and Mountain Lion.

I found this link to another user having what seems to be the same problem, but there are no responses:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3372462?start=0&tstart=0

Any ideas why Snooze stopped working in my iCal alerts?

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem. I keep missing meetings afer hitting snooze and not getting reminded again.